# $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((1+1/n)(1+2/n)...(1+n/n))^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Hi anyone knows how to evaluate this limit?

I let $P$ = the limit

Then $\log$ both sides to bring the $1/n$ power down.

After that I integrate it by parts and gotten until

$\log P = 2\log2 - 1$

But from here how to get rid of the $\log$ and get $P$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $\log P=2\log2-1\implies P=e^{\log4-1}=4e^{-1}$

Comment: Try using limit as a sum of definite integral.

Comment: Log can be base 10 also?

Comment: In my country, we use $\ln$ for $\log_e$. However, $\log$ is world-wide conventional .

Comment: It seems unlikely that you got common logarithms by integration.  Because of the $-1$ in the equation, it can only be true for one base.

Comment: I use sum notation to get integral (0-1) log (1+x) and integrate by parts to get 2log2 - 1 after substituting 1 and 0